# Proof the Laplace expansion of determinant doesn't depend on row or column of expansion

Tags: matrices, determinant, inverse

The Laplace expansion over the first row the determinant of an $(n\times n)$ Matrix $A$ is defined as

$det(A)=\sum_{j=1}^{3}(-1)^{1+j}M_{1j}a_{1j}$ where $M_{ij}$ is the determinant of the $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ formed by removing the $i$th row and $jth$ column of A.

I am trying to prove that the expansion gives the same result independent over the choice of row over which it is expanded.

My attempt so far has to be consider a new matrix $B$ created from $A$ by permuting the rows such that the first row of $B$ is the $i$th row of $A$. As row $i$ in A is swapped $(i-1)$ times to become the first row of $B$, we can say that

$det(B)=(-1)^{i-1}det(A)$

I am now trying to reach a result that states

$det(A)=\sum_{j=1}^{3}(-1)^{i+j}M_{ij}a_{ij}$

which would prove that the expansion can be computed along any choice of row $i$ assuming that the first row gives the determinant, im not sure how to get to this point from my matrix $B$

Comment: Notice that $(-1)^{i+j} = (-1)^{(i-1)+(1+j)}$. Factor out the $(-1)^{i-1}$ and you're done!

Comment: I tried that but I was left with $det(A)=\sum_{j=1}^{3}(-1)^{i+j}M_{1j}a_{1j}$ and i'm not sure how to deal with the $M_{1j}a_{1j}$ terms as I want them to look like $M_{ij}a_{ij}$

Comment: I think it's cleaner to see it this way. You don't have to swap $(i-1)$ times but rather just one time. Just swap the $i$ and $1$ rows. Let $B$ be the matrix with the swaps, and let the minors of $B$ be $N_{ij}$. Since the swap affected the minor too, we have $N_{1j} = -M_{ij}$. We also have $\det B = - \det A$. Putting these two minus signs together should cancel out. The same logic applies in your proof by noting that you also have $(i-1)$ swaps in the minor but writing it out is messy.

Comment: That works, thank you